# google script parse xml

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets

XML:

```
 <issues total_count="210" offset="0" limit="25" type="array">
    <issue>
    <id>22079</id>
    <project id="21" name="name1"/>
    <description>Some text</description>
    <start_date>2017-11-22</start_date>
    <custom_fields type="array">
    <custom_field id="36" name="cf_36">
    <value>cf_36_value</value>
    </custom_field>
    <custom_field id="28" name="cf_28">
    <value>cf_28_value</value>
    </custom_field>
    <value type="array"/>
    </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
    </issue>
```

Hi, I'm trying to get the value of all the fields in the loop, then insert data into sheet.

```
function APIRequest (url,sheet) {

  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  var DOC = Xml.parse(xml);
  var issues = DOC.issues.issue

  for(var c=0; c<issues.length;c++){
   var issue = issues[c];
    var id = issue.getElement('id').getText();

  sheet.appendRow([id]);
  }
 }
```

My problem is that I cann't get the values "cf_36_value" from XML for each "issue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? You can parse XML data using XML Service Service for Google Apps Script. From your question and script, I understood what you want to do as follows.

- You want to create the script using Google Apps Script.
- There are several elements of "issue" in "issues".
- There are one element of "custom_fields" in "issue".
- There are several elements of "custom_field" in "custom_fields".
- You want the value under the element with the attribute of `id="36"`.

  - That's `cf_36_value`.

The modified script reflected above points is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
var data = XmlService.parse(xml);
var issue = data.getRootElement().getChildren("issue");
var result = [];
for (i in issue) {
  var custom_field = issue[i].getChild("custom_fields").getChildren("custom_field");
  for (j in custom_field) {
    if (custom_field[j].getAttribute("id").getValue() == 36) { // If you want values of other ID, please set this.
      result.push([custom_field[j].getChild("value").getValue()]);
    }
  }
}
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
```

#### References :

- [XML Service Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. And can you show us whole XML data? I would like to modify my answer. Since the XML data of your question is incompleted,  I worry about it.