# Googlescript trouble parsing XML

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pretty sure this is a dumb question (I'm new to googlescript) but after a lot of googling and hitting the wall for several hours I would really appreciate your help to show me how write a googlescript to retrieve the contents of "celular" and "mensagem" from the following xml feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="https://www.twwwireless.com.br/reluzcap/wsreluzcap">
  <xs:schema id="OutDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="OutDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="SMSMO">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="seunum" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="celular" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="mensagem" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="datarec" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="dataenv" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="datastatus" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="op" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <OutDataSet xmlns="">
      <SMSMO diffgr:id="SMSMO1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <seunum>MSG                 </seunum>
        <celular>5511984326293       </celular>
        <mensagem>2</mensagem>
        <status>MO</status>
        <datarec>2018-08-04T11:58:11.877-03:00</datarec>
        <dataenv>2018-08-04T11:58:12.45-03:00</dataenv>
        <datastatus>2018-08-04T11:58:12.45-03:00</datastatus>
        <op>2</op>
      </SMSMO>
    </OutDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

If I run the following script

```
  var document = XmlService.parse(bggXml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();     
  var entries = new Array();
  entries = root.getChildren('OutDataSet');
  Logger.log(entries);
```

the Log returns

> [18-08-05 14:40:23:594 BRT] []

if I run the following script

```
  var document = XmlService.parse(bggXml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();     
  var entries = new Array();
  entries = root.getAllContent();
  Logger.log(entries);
```

The log returns

> [18-08-05 14:46:41:593 BRT] [[Element: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema]/>], [Element: ]]

and if I run the following script

```
  var document = XmlService.parse(bggXml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();     
  var entries = new Array();
  entries = root.getChildren();
  Logger.log(entries);
```

the log is the same as the previous

> [18-08-05 14:52:13:581 BRT] [[Element: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema]/>], [Element: ]]

Comment: Did you see the following Stack Overflow post?  [google script parse xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476476/google-script-parse-xml)

Comment: that `[18-08-04 07:58:22:677 PDT]` invalidates the XML ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler That's the `Logger.log()` timestamp. The XML is valid.

Comment: @Sandy Good, I saw the post you are referencing but can't figure out how to set it up according to my xml data. Could you please help?
Martin, the post to the API requires a UserID and Password and I guess that why you see the 404. But be sure the xml I included in my post is the actual response I'm getting.
Many thanks for both of you. Looking forward for extra help

Comment: `SoapService` & `WSDL API` had been depreciated... else it would be something alike `var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl("https://webservices.twwwireless.com.br/reluzcap/wsreluzcap.asmx?WSDL");` ...this is not really XML, but a SOAP envelope - and hence those classes were deprecated, would suggest to use PHP-SOAP or cURL on GCE, instead (eg. to scan into a simple database, which can be queried via `UrlFetchApp` then).

Comment: @MartinZeitler, many thanks for clarifying XML x SOAP envelope. So my take from your answer is that there is no simple way to extract the values of the fields using standard Googlescript classes, correct? Your suggestions seem too complicated for a novice in the field like myself, unless you can point out a tutorial os step by step example to me...Anyway many thanks for taking the time to help me

Comment: @SimonSchvartzman this would be the PHP SOAP client: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php - there are others, eg. for Java; but in App Script with deprecated `SoapService` , this might not be the right environment for consuming SOAP services, anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your script, how about these modification and sample? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as two of them.

#### Modified script :

When you use XmlService, you can modify your script as follows.

```
var bggXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DataSet xmlns="https://www.twwwireless.com.br/reluzcap/wsreluzcap">  <xs:schema id="OutDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">    <xs:element name="OutDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">      <xs:complexType>        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">          <xs:element name="SMSMO">            <xs:complexType>              <xs:sequence>                <xs:element name="seunum" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />                <xs:element name="celular" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />                <xs:element name="mensagem" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />                <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />                <xs:element name="datarec" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />                <xs:element name="dataenv" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />                <xs:element name="datastatus" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />                <xs:element name="op" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />              </xs:sequence>            </xs:complexType>          </xs:element>        </xs:choice>      </xs:complexType>    </xs:element>  </xs:schema>  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">    <OutDataSet xmlns="">      <SMSMO diffgr:id="SMSMO1" msdata:rowOrder="0">        <seunum>MSG                 </seunum>        <celular>5511984326293       </celular>        <mensagem>2</mensagem>        <status>MO</status>        <datarec>2018-08-04T11:58:11.877-03:00</datarec>        <dataenv>2018-08-04T11:58:12.45-03:00</dataenv>        <datastatus>2018-08-04T11:58:12.45-03:00</datastatus>        <op>2</op>      </SMSMO>    </OutDataSet>  </diffgr:diffgram></DataSet>';
var document = XmlService.parse(bggXml);
var rootChildren = document.getRootElement().getChildren();
var res = {};
rootChildren.forEach(function(e) {
  if (e.getName() == "diffgram") {
    var c = e.getChild("OutDataSet").getChild("SMSMO").getChildren();
    c.forEach(function(f) {
      res[f.getName()] = f.getValue().trim()
    });
  }
});
Logger.log(res.celular); // 5511984326293
Logger.log(res.mensagem); // 2
```

#### Sample script :

When you use regex, you can use the following sample script. `bggXml` is the same with above.

```
var res1 = bggXml.match(/<celular>([\d ]+)<\/celular>/i)[1].trim();
var res2 = bggXml.match(/<mensagem>([\d ]+)<\/mensagem>/i)[1].trim();
Logger.log(res1); // 5511984326293
Logger.log(res2); // 2
```

#### Note :

- In this modified script, it supposes that "diffgram" and "OutDataSet" have one element, respectively. If you want to retrieve values from XML that "diffgram" and "OutDataSet" have several elements, please modify script.

#### Reference :

- [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)

If these are not what you want, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Leverage Apps Script's [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service) to parse the document. That class has functions that you can use to drill down to the appropriate elements in the document and extract the desired information.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It's not deprecated. Check the Apps Script documentation.

Comment: indeed, just class `XML` and `SoapService` where deprecated... while consuming a SOAP service by manual programming is nevertheless quite some effort, because one needs to maintain the headers and the envelope, which may contain authentication, a nonce and/or a request sequence number... vs. just loading a `WSDL` file and consuming the service.

Comment: @dimudesigns, thanks for your suggestion, it was exactly what I tried for several hours (and failed miserably) before posting my request for help. You seem to know how to do it, would you be so kind to share a short example using my feed? I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @SimonSchvartzman Update your post with your attempts thus far. You're more likely to get help by showing some measure of effort on your part.

Comment: @dimudesigns I did as suggested, just showing 3 of the I don't know how many attempts I have done so far. Many thanks